# Is there a way to use GitHub for Mac for GitHub remote and CLI for other remote?

Tags: command-line, git, version-control, github, versioning

The GitHub for Mac app says it'll only work with the Git origin remote. This means that it'll only work with one remote.

My current remote is used to push to Heroku. Is there a way to set my origin remote to GitHub and then just set another remote to Heroku for pushing via the command line?

This way I can leverage the full features of the GitHub for Mac app but still be able to push to Heroku via the Git CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git remote rename origin heroku
git remote add origin git://github.com/....
```

The `remote rename` command updates the branch configuration, so that running `git push` without any arguments will now push to `heroku` automatically.

If this doesn't happen for some reason, do it manually:

```
git config branch.master.remote heroku
```